# Reflection property of integrals clarification

Tags: calculus, integration

If I have an integral $$ \int_a^b f(c-x)$$ What would the reflection look like? Is it going to be $$ \int_{-b}^{-a} f(x+c) $$ or $$ \int_{-b}^{-a} f(x-c) $$ I thought it would be the second option but according to my book I’m wrong and the correct answer is the first option. Any explanations welcome to clarify my misunderstanding. I thought to obtain $ f(-x) $  I should multiply $ (c-x) $ by $-1$ but it seems I only need to multiply the $x$ by $-1$. I did draw a rough graph to convince myself but I still don’t understand conceptually.
Thank you for answering

Comment: This function is even, so it has the property $f(x) = f(-x)$, which is why you end up with $f(x+c)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is true is that
$$\int_a^b F(x)dx=\int_{-b}^{-a}F(-x)dx$$
for $F$ any regular function. Here, since the function you are trying to integrate is given by
$$F(x)=f(c-x),$$
then you can check that $F(-x)=f(c-(-x))=f(x+c)$, leading to the correct answer.